# read json array in jade / pug (writing the iteration loop in jade)

Tags: json, pug

Can someone help me write my jade file to properly read my variables from json?

My Json file looks like:

```
[
 { "name":"Little Engine","desc":"I am the first post"},
 {"name":"Mighty mouse","desc":"I am the second post"}
]
```

I'm able to properly read the file and add it to jade using gulp. (which places the array into a "data" object.

This is where I get stuck. `p=data`

returns `<p>[object Object],[object Object]</p>` so I know the data is getting passed through.

I can access one of the object by doing `p=data[1].name`

But I just can't figure out how to loop to get each object. Since I don't know how to put the # in data[#].

Answer (score 5):

Ok... never mind, this was easier that I thought.

```
- each dot in data
  p  #{dot.name} ... #{dot.desc}
```

Thanks anyway.